# dplyr::summarize_at – sort columns by order of variables passed, then by order of functions applied

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, summarize

**Problem**

By using `dplyr::summarize_at()` (or equivalent), I would like to get a table of summaries in which columns are sorted first by **(G)** order of grouping variables used, then by **(V)** order of variables passed and lastly  by **(F)** order of functions applied. The default order is determined first by G, then by F and lastly by V.

**Example**

The code:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

q025 <- partial(quantile, probs  = 0.025, na.rm = TRUE)
q975 <- partial(quantile, probs  = 0.975, na.rm = TRUE)

vars_to_summarize <- c("height", "mass")

my_summary <- starwars %>% 
    filter(skin_color  %in% c("gold", "green")) %>% 
    group_by(skin_color) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars_to_summarize, funs(q025, mean, q975))
```

Results in:

```
my_summary
## A tibble: 2 x 7
##   skin_color height_q025 mass_q025 height_mean mass_mean height_q975 mass_q975
##        <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
## 1       gold     167.000      75.0         167        75      167.00      75.0
## 2      green      79.375      22.7         169        NA      204.75     110.4
```

And the desired order of variables should be:

```
skin_color, height_q025, height_mean, height_q975, mass_q025, mass_mean, mass_q975
```

I would like to use something like this (naively simple) code:

```
my_summary  %>% 
    select(everything(), starts_with(vars_to_summarize))
```

But it does not work. Even this code does not work as I expect
(even though it's not a general solution I seek):

```
my_summary  %>% 
    select(everything(),
           starts_with(vars_to_summarize[1]),
           starts_with(vars_to_summarize[2]))
```

Most probably `everything()` should always be the last argument in `select()`.

**To generalize**

Say, I have:

1. *N* grouping variables ("gr_") that I pass to `group_by()`,
2. *L* variables ("var_") that have to be summarized and
3. *M* summary functions to apply ("fun_").

In general, the desired order of variables
in the summary table should follow the pattern:

```
gr_1, gr_2, ..., gr_N,   
var_1_fun_1, var_1_fun_2, ..., var_1_fun_M,  
var_2_fun_1, var_2_fun_2, ..., var_2_fun_M, 
...,
var_L_fun_1, var_L_fun_2, ..., var_L_fun_M
```

Comment: Try with `my_summary %>% select(c(matches(vars_to_summarize[1]), matches(vars_to_summarize[2])))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `matches` and `grep`

```
my_summary %>%
    select(grep(paste(vars_to_summarize, collapse="|"), names(.), invert = TRUE), 
           matches(vars_to_summarize[1]),
           matches(vars_to_summarize[2]))
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#    skin_color height_q025 height_mean height_q975 mass_q025 mass_mean mass_q975
#       <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1       gold     167.000         167      167.00      75.0        75      75.0
#2      green      79.375         169      204.75      22.7        NA     110.4
```

---

If there are many columns, then another option would be to remove the substring from `_` in the column names, `match` with the 'vars_to_summarize' and `order` within the `select`

```
my_summary %>% 
   select(order(match(sub("_.*", "", names(.)), vars_to_summarize, nomatch = 0)))
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#    skin_color height_q025 height_mean height_q975 mass_q025 mass_mean mass_q975
#       <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1       gold     167.000         167      167.00      75.0        75      75.0
#2      green      79.375         169      204.75      22.7        NA     110.4
```

Comment: Brilliant!!!☺ Just as I intend to have variables, which contain `_` in their names, regular expression `sub("(.*)_.*?$", "\\1", names(.))` was more appropriate.